# Scrapy Crawler gets terminated at random pages

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy. I'm crawling the r/india subreddit using a recursive parser to store the title, upvotes and URLs of each thread. It works all fine but the Scraper ends unexpectedly with a weird error that shows:

```
2018-04-29 00:01:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing 
<GET https://www.reddit.com/r/india/?count=50&after=t3_8fh5nv> (referer: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/india/?count=25&after=t3_8fiqd5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in 
iter_errback
yield next(it)
File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", 
line 30, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", 
line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", 
line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 
58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File 
"C:\Users\jayes\myredditscraper\myredditscraper\spiders\scrapereddit.py", 
line 28, in parse
   yield Request(url=(next_page),callback=self.parse)
File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 
25, in __init__
   self._set_url(url)
File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 
62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:
2018-04-29 00:01:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

And the error comes at random pages each time the spider is run, making it impossible for me to detect what's causing the problem. Here's my redditscraper.py file which contains the code(I've also used Pipeline and Items.py but that doesn't contain any problems I feel)

```
import scrapy
import time
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from myredditscraper.items import MyredditscraperItem
class ScraperedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'scrapereddit'
allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/india/']
def parse(self,response):
    next_page=''
    titles=response.css("a.title::text").extract()
    links=response.css("a.title::attr(href)").extract()
    votes=response.css("div.score.unvoted::attr(title)").extract()
    for item in zip(titles,links,votes):

        new_item = MyredditscraperItem()
        new_item['title']=item[0]
        new_item['link']=item[1]
        new_item['vote']=item[2]
        yield new_item

        next_page = response.css("span.next- 
button").css('a::attr(href)').extract()[0]

    if next_page is not None:

        yield Request(url=(next_page),callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Use `Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)` to be sure that you get the absolute url when the `href` attribute contains a  relative path.

Comment: Tried but again the same error. Used shell to find out that it was happening because reddit was asking for login,and i tried using requests but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As your exception says

> ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:

thats means you try to scrap an invalid url - missing `http://` or `https://` in the url.

I guess the problem is not in the `start_urls` because otherwise the parse function won't be called. The problem is in the parse function.

When `yield Request` is called you need to check if `next_page` contains schema. it seems like the urls you parse are relative links, so you have two options to continue scrap those links without facing this exception:

1. Passing absolute url.
2. Skipping relative urls.